# Third Chern class of an ideal sheaf of a curve on a quadric hypersurface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $X$ be a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb P^4$ and let $Z\subset X$ be a algebraic subset of pure dimension $1$ on $X$. Consider $Z$ smooth.

I want to find the $c_3(I_{Z/X})$.

> I want somebody to help me verify if the calculations below are OK, also I need some help, hind or reference when $Z$ is singular.

Take the Euler characteristic of the following short exact sequence

\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow I_{Z/X}\rightarrow \mathcal O_X\rightarrow \mathcal O_{Z/X}\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
we have $\chi(I_{Z/X})=1-\chi(\mathcal O_{Z/X})=g$, where $g$ is the arithmetic genus of $Z$.

By the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem
\begin{align}
\chi(I_{Z/X})&=\deg\left[Ch(I_{Z/X})\cdot td(TX)\right]_3\\
             &=\deg\left[(1+c_1+\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-2c_2)+\frac{1}{6}(c_1^3-3c_1c_2+3c_3))\cdot (1+\frac{1}{2}c_1^{'}+\frac{1}{12}((c_1^{'})^2+c_2^{'})+\frac{1}{24}(c_1^{'}c_2^{'}))\right]_3
\end{align}

where $[\ ]_3$ is the term of degree 3, $c_i=c_i(I_{Z/X})$ and $c_i^{'}=c_i(TX)$ for $i=1,2,3$.

By the other hand $c_1=0$, $c_2=[Z]$ (the fundamental cycle of $Z$), $c_1^{'}=3H$, $c_2^{'}=4H^2$ and $H=c_1(\mathcal O_X(1))$.

So
\begin{align}
\chi(I_{Z/X})&=\deg\left[(1-[Z]+\frac{1}{2}c_3)\cdot (1+\frac{3}{2}H+\frac{13}{12}H^2+\frac{1}{2}H^3)\right]_3\\
    g &=\deg\left(\frac{1}{2}H^3+\frac{1}{2}c_3-\frac{3}{2}[Z]\cdot H\right).
\end{align}

finally, we have the identity
$$ (g-1)H^3-3[Z]\cdot H =c_3$$

Comment: I follow until your final line. How are you evaluating the degree? And if this is on $X$, then don't we have $H^3 = 2$ and $[Z].H = \deg Z$?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, $H^3=2$ and $[Z]\cdot H=\deg Z$. After the penultimate line I take $\frac{g}{2}H^3= \frac{1}{2}H^3+\frac{1}{2}c_3-\frac{3}{2}[Z]\cdot H$. I made a signal mistake at the final line: $(g-1)H^3+3[Z]\cdot H=c_3$. Well, now I think that, maybe, a better conclusion is $(g-1)+3\deg Z=c_3$ if I consider $c_3H^3=c_3$  for abuse of notation.

Comment: OK, but the left hand side $\chi(I_{Z/X}) = g$ is just a number that you seem to be treating as though it's a cohomology class when you take degrees on the right hand side. I would think you should just get $c_3 = (2g - 1) + 3\deg Z$?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it very well, but in my notation above $c_3=nH^3$ where $n$ is a integer; so, $\deg (\frac{1}{2}H^2+ \frac{1}{2}c_3-\frac{3}{2}[Z]\cdot H)=1+ n-3\deg (Z)$, right? Then $n=g-1+ 3\deg (Z)$. By the oher hand, my first thought was that $\frac{g}{2}H^3=\frac{1}{2}H^2 +\frac{1}{2}c_3-\frac{3}{2}[Z]\cdot H$ because after take degrees I have $\deg (\frac{g}{2}H^3)=g=\deg(\frac{1}{2}H^2 +\frac{1}{2}c_3-\frac{3}{2}[Z]\cdot H)$.